# Firebase push notification terminated state on notification click navigated to chat screen its not working as expected stuck in splash screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

here i am pasting the code of main.dart file

```
class NavigationService {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName, {Map<String, dynamic>? arguments}) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments) ?? Future.value();
  }
}

Future<void>main() async {

await runZonedGuarded (
    () async{
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
        Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
        ///firebase initialize
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
    
        NotificationServices.getFirebaseMessagingToken();
        NotificationServices().firebaseInit();
        FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
        PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
          FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
          return true;
        };

        runApp((EasyLocalization(
        child: const MyApp())));
        DependencyInjection.init();
      },
    (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
  );

}
```

code inside Myapp class materialApp.

```
 child: MaterialApp(
                navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
                scaffoldMessengerKey: rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.generateRoute,
                navigatorObservers:[AppRoutes.observer],
                theme: ThemeManager.lightTheme,
                localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
                supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
                locale: context.locale,
                initialRoute:AppRoutes.splashScreen,

              ),
```

below pasting the code of NotficationService class.

```
class NotificationServices {
  static String? firebasePushToken;

  static FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void initLocalNotifications(RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings(
        '@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    var iosInitializationSettings =
    const DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSetting,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
        handleMessage( message);
        },
        );

  }

  void firebaseInit() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      initLocalNotifications(message);
      showNotification(message);
    });



    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      handleMessage(message);
      // Use NavigationService.navigateTo or other navigation logic here
    });
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    const AndroidNotificationChannel androidNotificationChannel =
    AndroidNotificationChannel("Q-channel", "QChats",
        importance: Importance.max);

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        androidNotificationChannel.id, androidNotificationChannel.name,
        channelDescription: "qualfon-chats",
        importance: Importance.high,
        priority: Priority.high);
    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
    DarwinNotificationDetails(
        presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
    );

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification?.title.toString(),
          message.notification?.body.toString(),
          notificationDetails);
    });

  }

  static Future<String?> getFirebaseMessagingToken() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    log('User granted firebase permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

    /// Needed for ios foreground notification
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    await firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      if (token != null) {
        firebasePushToken = token;
        log("fcm token : $token");
      }
    });
    return firebasePushToken;
  }

  ///Handling incoming message

  static Future<void> handleMessage (RemoteMessage? message) async {
    print("handling msg");
    if (message == null) {
      return;
    }else {
      // ChatListingBloc().add(FetchChatList());
      print(message.notification?.body);
      print(message.notification?.title);
      print(message.data["chatId"]);
      String senderId=message.data["senderId"];
      String senderName="Unknown";
      // await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      if (message.notification?.title != null){
        senderName=convertName(message.notification?.title??"") ;
      }
      String? receiverId=await PrefManager.retrieveValue(Constants.id);// This will the user who receives the notification
      String senderImageUrl= await GetImageURlsByErpId.getImageUrlByErpId(senderId)??"";
      print('reciverId $receiverId');
      if(receiverId != null){
       // ChatListingBloc().add(FetchChatList());
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
       NavigationService.navigateTo( AppRoutes.chatAuth,
           arguments:{
             'name':senderName,
             'profileUrl':senderImageUrl,
             'chatId':message.data["chatId"],
             'userId':senderId,
             'currentUserId':receiverId,
           });

     } else {
       print("user id null");
     }
      print("tapped notification msg");
    }

  }


}
```

here my issue is on terminated state notification click is navigated to chat Screen but when click the back button it will stuck on to splash screen then we need to rerun the app again, so here sometimes the chat screen appear twice, i think there should be some issue on the code to navigation in terminated state, but foreground & background states are working fine , and one more thing in terminated state sometimes no notifications are coming but when we reopen the app then it comes